# Limpiar valores de un Label, Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Buen dia, tengo un pequeño problema con tkinter, Y es que cada vez que actualizo el valor del `Label` El nuevo valor se sobre pone encima y el anterior aun queda marcado por detras. Hay forma de limpiar el anterior?

Dejo captura del problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven el 25 se pone encima del anterior.

Esta es mi Funcion

```
def total(): 
  items = listitems2.get(0,tkinter.END)
  A = "".join(items)
  CD = (A.split('S/.')[1:])
  b= [int(x) for x in CD]
  totall = Label(ventana,text=("S/.",sum(b)))
  totall.place(x=220,y=100)
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para que el anterior valor se limpie al agregarse el nuevo valor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en lugar de actualizar el texto de la etiqueta **estás creando una nueva etiqueta cada vez que actualizas el resultado**.

Define la etiqueta `totall` en el *ámbito global* (fuera de la función). A partir de aquí tienes dos opciones:

1. **Modifica el texto de la etiqueta mediante su método `config`:**

```py
from tkinter import *

def total():
    # ...
    totall.config(text='nuevo-texto')


ventana = TK()

totall = Label(ventana, text='texto-inicial')
totall.place(x=220,y=100)

# ...

ventana.mainloop()
```

2. **Utiliza un objeto `StringVar` y asignalo como `textvariable` de la etiqueta:**

```py
from tkinter import *

def total():
    # ...
    totall_text.set('nuevo-texto')


ventana = TK()

totall_text = StringVar()
totall_text.set('texto-inicial')

totall = Label(ventana, textvariable=totall_text)
totall.place(x=220,y=100)

# ...

ventana.mainloop()
```

Un saludo!